# Multiple parents for entries with `glossaries`

Tags: glossaries

I am using the package `glossaries` to produce an index. I am using `sub-entries`and the field `parent`in my glossary entries definition. In order to ease the use of my index I would like some entries to be displayed several times and in different places. My first try was to simply declare in the glossary entry that the entry has severyl parents by setting

```
parent={key1,key2}
```

However it seems that this is not supported by the `glossaries` package. Is there any other way?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Multiple parents aren't supported by `glossaries`. If you have hyperlinks, there would be an ambiguity as to which glossary entry commands like `\gls` would link to. There are however ways to get around it.

**Approach 1:**

Define two entries with the same name but different parents and use the relevant one in the context of its given parent. This works best if you don't have a location list. Example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=index,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{parent1}
{%
  name={parent 1},%
  description={First parent}%
}

\newglossaryentry{parent2}
{%
  name={parent 2},%
  description={Second parent}%
}

\newglossaryentry{child1}
{%
  name={sample},
  description={an example},%
  parent={parent1}%
}

\newglossaryentry{child2}
{%
  name={sample},%
  description={an example},%
  parent={parent2}%
}

\begin{document}

Reference \gls{child1} in the context of \gls{parent1}.

Reference \gls{child2} in the context of \gls{parent2}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The first reference links to the entry under `First parent`. The second reference links to the entry under `Second parent`.

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Approach 2:**

This approach is more advanced. It stores a list of labels with which a child entry is associated and defines `\mgls` to iterate through the list using `\glsadd` for all except the final label for which it uses `\gls`. Example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=index]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{parent1}
{%
  name={parent 1},%
  description={First parent}%
}

\newglossaryentry{parent2}
{%
  name={parent 2},%
  description={Second parent}%
}

\newcommand{\dochild}[3]{%
  \listcsadd{#2.labels}{#3.#2}%
  \newglossaryentry{#3.#2}%
  {%
     #1,parent={#3}%
  }%
}

% syntax: \addchild{label}{parent list}{key=val list}
\newcommand*{\addchild}[3]{%
  \csdef{#1.labels}{}%
  \forcsvlist{\dochild{#3}{#1}}{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\mgls}[2][]{%
  \def\glslastlabel{}%
  \forlistcsloop
  {%
    \ifdefempty{\glslastlabel}{}{\glsadd[#1]{\glslastlabel}}%
    \def\glslastlabel
  }%
  {#2.labels}%
  \gls[#1]{\glslastlabel}%
}

\newcommand*{\mglsadd}[2][]{%
  \forlistcsloop
  {%
    \glsadd[#1]%
  }%
  {#2.labels}%
}

\addchild{sample}{parent1,parent2}%
{%
  name={sample},%
  description={an example}%
}

\begin{document}

\mgls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Here `\mgls` will link to the entry under the last named parent used when the child entry was defined with `\addchild`.

[image: Image of resulting document]

If you would rather link to a different glossary entry, you can use `\mglsadd` and explicitly use `\gls` with the label in the form *parent*`.`*child*. Like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=index]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{parent1}
{%
  name={parent 1},%
  description={First parent}%
}

\newglossaryentry{parent2}
{%
  name={parent 2},%
  description={Second parent}%
}

\newcommand{\dochild}[3]{%
  \listcsadd{#2.labels}{#3.#2}%
  \newglossaryentry{#3.#2}%
  {%
     #1,parent={#3}%
  }%
}

% syntax: \addchild{label}{parent list}{key=val list}
\newcommand*{\addchild}[3]{%
  \csdef{#1.labels}{}%
  \forcsvlist{\dochild{#3}{#1}}{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\mgls}[2][]{%
  \def\glslastlabel{}%
  \forlistcsloop
  {%
    \ifdefempty{\glslastlabel}{}{\glsadd[#1]{\glslastlabel}}%
    \def\glslastlabel
  }%
  {#2.labels}%
  \gls[#1]{\glslastlabel}%
}

\newcommand*{\mglsadd}[2][]{%
  \forlistcsloop
  {%
    \glsadd[#1]%
  }%
  {#2.labels}%
}

\addchild{sample}{parent1,parent2}%
{%
  name={sample},%
  description={an example}%
}

\begin{document}

\mglsadd{sample}\gls{parent1.sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces the same looking result as previously, but now the sample entry links to the entry under the first parent instead of the second parent.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find this idea of multiplying entry with same name but different parent in the user manual.

Comment: the second approach works fine for me! Still it seems to me that this feature could be added to the `glossaries` package to allow two and more parents and the use of the same command `\gls` or `\glsadd`. It looks to me it would be more in the spirit of the package.

Comment: @yann.pequignot You can [log it as a feature request](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/feature-request.html) if you like. I only uploaded a new version of `glossaries` a few days ago, but if it's logged, I'll see it when I work on the next version.