LaTeX Glossaries Child Displaying Incorrectly
I am trying to make a glossary translating some terms from English to Russian, with a child node. Currently have the following:
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,final]{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}

%Classical Mechanics
\newglossary*{classMech}{Classical Mechanics}

\newglossaryentry{classMech:Momentum}{
    type ={classMech},
    name ={Momentum},
    description = { \foreignlanguage{Russian}{Импульс} }    
}

\newglossaryentry{classMech:AngularMomentum}{
    type ={classMech},
    name ={Angular Momentum},
    description = {\foreignlanguage{Russian}{момент импульса}},
    parent = {classMech:Momentum}
}

\makenoidxglossaries
%\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printnoidxglossaries
%\printglossaries

\end{document}


It displays as follows:

I would like the Angular momentum to be displayed below the Momentum term, with its own bolded header saying angular momentum.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

If I understand correctly, you simply need to remove the line parent = {classMech:Momentum}.

Check out the glossaries package manual, section "2. Package Options" on page 96.

% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=2mm 2mm -4.5cm -.5cm}

% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Russian
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is no longer required (since 2018)
\usepackage[main=english, russian]{babel}

% \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=index,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\newglossary*{classMech}{Classical Mechanics}

% required for \printnoidxglossaries
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{classMech:Momentum}{
    type = {classMech},
    name = {Momentum},
    description = {\foreignlanguage{russian}{Импульс}},
}

\newglossaryentry{classMech:AngularMomentum}{
    type = {classMech},
    name = {Angular Momentum},
    description = {\foreignlanguage{russian}{момент импульса}},
    parent = {classMech:Momentum}
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printnoidxglossary[type=classMech]

\end{document}


This defeats the point of having Angular Momentum be displayed as a sub element of Momentum

I don't understand your request then, can you provide an image of the desired output?

I have updated the answer. Is this what you were looking for?

No. Please see this post for examples of what I want it to look like: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122799/multiple-parents-for-entries-with-glossaries

You simply forgot to include style=index as a package option. I will update the answer :)

Thank you so much! This works.
